# Python email sender, Gives me error that I had not experienced when I had it working for 2.7 (have updated syntax for 3.x)

Tags: python, email, python-3.x

I've written a python email sender, that signs into gmail/yahoo. I've just downloaded python 3.4 (up from python 2.7). I cannot figure out my error, which is

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Parker McKillop/Desktop/Email bomber.py", line 35, in <module>
    for i in range(1, total+1):
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
import smtplib
import getpass
import sys

server = input ('Server Mail: ')
user = input('Username: ')
passwd = getpass.getpass('Password: ')


to = input('\nTo: ')
subject = input('Subject:')
body = input('Message:')
total = input('Number of send: ')

if server == 'gmail':
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    port = 587
elif server == 'yahoo':
    smtp_server = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
    port = 25
else:
    print('Applies only to gmail and yahoo')
    sys.exit()

print ('')

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo()
    if smtp_server == "smtp.gmail.com":
            server.starttls()
    server.login(user,passwd)
    for i in range(1, total+1):
        subject = os.urandom(9)
        msg = 'From: ' + user + '\nSubject: ' + subject + '\n' + body
        server.sendmail(user,to,msg)
        print ("\rTotal emails sent: %i" % i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    server.quit()
    print ('\n Done !!!')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ('[-] Canceled')
    sys.exit()
except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print ('\n[!] The username or password you entered is incorrect.')
    sys.exit()
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: "Email bomber" doesn't sound like a project I would like to help promote.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! This was just for my friend on april fools day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` in Python 3 always returns a string.  Thus, `total` will be a string, and when Python tries to execute `range(1, total+1)`, it fails.  You need to change the definition of `total` to:

```
total = int(input('Number of send: '))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, I will mark it as correct when stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Parker McKillop/Desktop/Email bomber.py", line 37, in <module>
    str(msg = 'From: ' + user + '\nSubject: ' + subject + '\n' + body)
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @user3108716: It should be enough to just explicitly call `str` on each of the variables as you're concatenating them: `msg = 'From: ' + str(user) + '\nSubject: ' + str(subject) + '\n' + str(body)`.